# Is it better to use 'till' or 'by' to denote time?

Tags: grammar

"I will give it to you by midnight."

```
          OR
```

"I wil give it to you till midnight."

Are both grammatically correct?
Which one sounds more natural?
Can you ommit "to you" in these sentences?

Comment: They have different meanings; the second one is the funnier of the two, but the first is probably the one you mean.
https://blog.harwardcommunications.com/2012/04/12/the-difference-between-by-and-until/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is different.

"I will give it to you by midnight" means that sometime between now and midnight I will give it to you.

"I will give it to you till midnight" that means that I will give it to you continuously from now until midnight. That is, that the action of "giving it" is an ongoing one that might last several hours. It's more than likely that "give it to you" in this sentence is a euphemism for sex.

You might have confused this with another construction:

> I will give you till midnight to <do something>

This means that I allow you the time between now and midnight to complete whatever action you have promised to me.

Comment: It is perfectly ordinary usage to say "I will give you the book till midnight" meaning you can keep it until,then.  Your claim that it is a euphemism strikes me as completely unfounded.

Comment: @Mary, of course if you explicitly say (or context establishes) it's a book rather than just "it", then it's no longer a euphemism.

Comment: On the contrary you would need context to establish that it is a euphemism.   It is not a normal construction.

Comment: @Mary I may just have a dirtier mind than you but I'm pretty sure "giving it to someone" is a well-established euphemism for sex. Based on comments on the question post, I wasn't the only one to read it this way.